# Problem about an ant walking up a hill

Tags: graphics, functions, animation

> An ant is walking up a hill given by $f(x)$. At what point can it see a blade of grass.

I've been working on this problem with *Mathematica* and by hand. Help with either would be fantastic. The blade of grass is given by the line segment from (32,1/5) and (32,8). The 2D hill is given by

$\quad \quad f(x)=(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2$

I am struggling to figure out how to set the equations so that I can solve the point on the hill line, especially because I have to qualify that the other point on the line (which slope equal to $f'(x)$) must intersect only between $y=1/5-8$ AND not intersect $h(x)$ again (which defines the hill).

As far as for the code goes, I can display the blade of grass and the hill with basic `Animate[Show["Hill","BladeofGrass"...]` functions, having defined `Hill` and `BladeofGrass` as plots. The problem is defining the line of sight for the ant, which needs to be the tangent line to the curve but cannot intersect the curve again! I was thinking about using a For-loop.

Any help, detailed or theoretical is much appreciated!

```
Hillheight[x_] := (1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2
Hill = Plot[(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2, {x, 0, 32}]
BladeofGrass =` ParametricPlot[{32, 1/5 + x}, {x, 0, 39/5}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]` 

Animate[Show[Hill, BladeofGrass], {n, 0, 32}]
```

These are some fragments of the code I've been working with for the Ant's line-of-sight.

```
ParametricPlot[{x + n, D[Hillheight[x], x]}, {x, 0, 32}
  For[n = 0, n < 32, n++, Plot[{x, D[Hillheight[x]]}, {x, 0, 32}]
```

Comment: Please don't use images for code.

Comment: Sorry! Just learning to work this.

Comment: Hint: a property of the tangent line you're looking for is that the line connecting the ant and the tangent point has the same orientation. So the trick is to set up general expressions for both, equate them and solve them using Solve.

Comment: Hint 2: You need the line connecting ant and blade tip to be at least as steep as the tangent line mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sjoerd points out, a good place to start is by recognising that the line from the ant to the tip of the grass must be a tangent to the curve. So you can solve for the x positions of the ant where this is true:

```
antx = x /. NSolve[(8 - f[x])/(32 - x) == f'[x], x, Reals]
(* {14.9475, 8.62026} *)
```

Here's a plot showing those points and the line-of-sight to the tip of the grass:

```
With[{points = Thread[{antx, f[antx]}]},
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 35}, Epilog -> {
    PointSize[Large], Point[points],
    Directive[Thick, Green], Line[{{32, 1/5}, {32, 8}}],
    Directive[Thin, Red, Dashed], Line[{#, {32, 8}}] & /@ points},
  PlotRange -> {0, 8}, Filling -> 0, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Clearly the ant at x=8.6 cannot see the grass as the line of sight intersects the hill. You can compute solutions for the line of sight to intersect the hill:

```
intersectionPoint[x_] := Solve[(f[x] + (x2 - x) f'[x] == f[x2]) && (x2 > x), x2, Reals]

intersectionPoint /@ antx
(* {{}, {{x2 -> 17.4015}}} *)
```

So for the ant at x=14.9 there are no solutions for the line-of-sight intersecting the hill and for the ant at x=8.6 there is one intersection, at x=17.4

Answer (score 5):

This may help

```
Hillheight[x_] := (1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2
Hill = Plot[(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2, {x, 0, 32},PlotRange -> {0, 8}];
BladeofGrass = ParametricPlot[{32, 1/5 + x}, {x, 0, 39/5}, PlotStyle -> {Green}];

line[xANT_, x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[{{xANT, Hillheight[xANT]}, {32, 8}}, x];

Manipulate[Show[Hill, BladeofGrass, Plot[line[xANT, x], {x, xANT, 32}]], {xANT, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Interpolating polynomial is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood it properly. Instead of Animate, looking at slope variations plots may also help determine points near tangency.

```
f[x_]=(1/16 x^2-2 x+80)/(1/16 x^2-2 x+20)^2;
Hillheight[x_]:=(1/16 x^2-2 x+80)/(1/16 x^2-2 x+20)^2;
Hill=Plot[Hillheight[x],{x,0,32}] 
BladeofGrass=ParametricPlot[{m/5+x, m  x },{x,0,35},{m,.05,0.5},PlotStyle->{Green}];
Show[{%,%%}, PlotRange->All]
```